# Not Understanding Logic to my function/variable

Tags: javascript, variables

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
```

Produces a random number from 0 - 3.....Great! But if I assign the function to variable "num"

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
console.log(num)
```

it will only produce the number 1. Why? I want `num` to be a random number from 0-3.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I think there's some code missing

Comment: I just edited - The result is 1. If var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) is ran in the console

Comment: See snippet. Seems to work as expected

Comment: Er, either that, or you just got unlucky a bunch of times in a row http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: the 10 times I ran that code I got 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1 ... seems OK

Comment: Notice, that you're not assigning the function to the variable, you're assigning a value returned by `Math.floor`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get distribution of pseudo-random numbers that seems to roughly match an equal distribution, as expected. Note that getting `1` a bunch of times is totally normal. The sequence `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1` is just as likely as the sequence `0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the assignment is just once, and you're probably printing the variable with the same value again.

You can do something like this where the function returns a random number every time you call it:

```js
var num = function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
console.log(num());
console.log(num());
console.log(num());
```

Comment: @j_nguyen Happy to help! Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

@karan Dhir has given a good answer, but to demonstrate using your own code snippet

```js
for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
    console.log(num)
}
```